# Split screen web with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to create a split screen with bootstrap. I googled other sources and did not find solutions. The plan is the site has a split screen with two pictures on the left and right side. There are a couple of links on the left picture. Now the problem I have are:
1. The picture on the left side is not exactly starts from left margin. I tried with left:0; did not help. 
2. I would like to have the pictures height equals exactly the screen size. No scroll. Now the height is 100%, and in order to see full length I have to scroll.I tried with height:auto, did not work. 
3. On the left picture, the link should be on top of the picture, now it's under. I tried also with url background img but failed.

So please take a look the link on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZqy1Xp

```
      <div class="col-md-6">

          <img src="http://www122.lunapic.com/editor/working       
             /144980254379614?49319erww"> 
          <ul>
              <li>link1</li>
              <li>link2</li>
          </ul>
       </img>

     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://www191.lunapic.com/do-not-
        link-here-use-hosting-instead/144978190397904?255757fw41"></img></div>
     </div>

  That's what I get. Any suggestions? Tks!
```

Comment: Link is dead, but anyway, adding external content is not recommended here. If it's an image, post it directly in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the grid, you'll have to remove the left and right padding from the `columns` and you can use background images to fill the each side of the screen completely.

You can use an **attribute "wildcard" selector** (See [MDN Attribure Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) to remove the padding from the columns as opposed to adding a class to each column individually.

```
.row-full > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

See working Snippet at Full Page.

```css
.leftside {
  background: url(http://www122.lunapic.com/editor/working/144980254379614?493195131) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100Vh;
}
.leftside .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.leftside .text a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.rightside {
  background: url(http://www191.lunapic.com/do-not-link-here-use-hosting-instead/144978190397904?2557574571) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100Vh;
}
.row-full > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .leftside .text {
    top: 60%;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-full">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="leftside">
        <div class="text">
          <a href="#">Some Link</a>
          <a href="#">Some Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="rightside">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Super:-) Tks a lot to every body's effort. Now I am going to remove the picture's link. XD

Comment: By the way, do you mind to explain a little bit of this line: .row-full > [class*='col-'] ,tks!

Comment: I see. Nice explanation.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: You're welcome and if your issue is solved please remember to mark your question as answered so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tried to edit your codepen example:

```
.col-md-6 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-left:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Tks! it does. any idea of how to remove the scroll but only limit the height to screen size:-)

Comment: See the other answer to your question. The solution suggested by David should work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the left picture starting more right than the margin of `div.container` is bootstraps column system adds padding to the elements with the column classes.

```
div.col-md-6 {
    padding: 0px
}
```

The css above should fix that. As for the pictures taking up the whole screen vertically, set the images to be 100vh (view height).

```
img {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Tks! Actually I tried with height:100vh. My sublime does not have such a package and I even tried to install it. But I just could not find the SublimeLint. It was downloaded to other folders seems to be. Anyway, I tried with height 100vh, the height is 100 but on the img both side has big white padding. I added also width:100vm, just not work:-(